# R: taskscheduleR for consecutive task

Tags: r, windows

I have around 10 automation tasks in R everyday.Some tasks are dependent on others.Normally, I use taskscheduleR package to set each tasks at different times (30 min difference),eg: 8:00, 8:30,..., 12:00. My problem is:
  1) For some tasks: the time to run ranges from 5 to 25 minutes ---> 30 min difference is too much
  2) Due to some infrequent errors, some task take more than 30 mins to run

Therefore, I just want to set a batch of tasks to complete, one after others. I prefer the solutions can be run in R

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Just come up with the answer, I never thought that it will be that easy.
Just consider 10 tasks as part of a big task, and schedule the big task:

```
#big task: bigtask.R
source('task1.R')
source('task2.R')
....
source('task10.R)
```

All we need is to schedule the 'bigtask.R' by using taskscheduleR addins

Comment: are you having to use the full directory in your source? i have an R package that i am running a task on, but I have to source the full path of the r scrip i want to run.